# A Reduction problem

Tags: calculus

$\int\frac{\cos^n(x)}{\sin(x)}\ dx$
I need a reduction formula.If this problem was answered please don't angry :(

Comment: I've formatted your question. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: That was Cos(x)^n/sin(x)

Comment: Thank you for help :)

Comment: And I assume that it's $(\cos x)^n$. The usual notation is $\cos^n x$

Comment: Yes  this is exactly I want

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you can rewrite it as

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{\cos^n(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}\sin(x)\,dx
\end{equation}

Then let $u=\cos(x)$ and you have

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{u^n}{u^2-1}\,du=\int u^{n-2}\,du+\int\frac{u^{n-2}}{u^2-1}\,du
\end{equation}

Can you finish it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your formula using $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2x$. Then the integral will be
$$\int\frac{\cos^n x}{\sin x} dx=\int\frac{\cos^{n-2} x}{\sin x} dx-\int\sin x\cos^{n-2} x\ dx$$
The last integral can be solved by substituting $y=\cos x$

Comment: Thank you so much everyone I solved it ;)